# Vim refresh rate too low when using fast key repeats on macOS

Tags: macos, mac, vim, macos-mojave

I'm experimenting with the macOS defaults for controlling the key repeat rate.

`defaults read -g InitialKeyRepeat`

`defaults read -g KeyRepeat`

I've set the repeat really high, as below:

`defaults write -g InitialKeyRepeat -int 10`

`defaults write -g KeyRepeat -int 1`

Vim doesn't like this settings, as can be seen on [this](https://streamable.com/tcecp) screen recording. The video shows how the button pressed (h, j, k or l) repeats on the screen when I've reached beginning or end of line or file. Note that it's only visual, no INSERT.

Is there any setting to improve refresh rate, or what could be the problem?

Comment: In normal mode, as purportedly here according to the status line, VIM does not print the letters `h`, `j`, `k`, and `l` when one types them.  Nor does the cursor move in that way in response.  This is not a standard configuration of VIM.

Comment: I do have my vimrc file and some plugins, but the error appears when augmenting the key repeat. Any idea on what could be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dissected my .vimrc and found the problem. 
The error was in a function made for echoing the current git branch that I got from [here](https://shapeshed.com/vim-statuslines/). I replaced that function with [this](https://github.com/itchyny/vim-gitbranch) plugin and the problem's gone.

The problem code is located somewhere in one of these functions:

```
function! GitBranch()
  return system("git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD 2>/dev/null | tr -d '\n'")
endfunction

function! StatuslineGit()
  let l:branchname = GitBranch()
  return strlen(l:branchname) > 0?'  '.l:branchname.' ':''
endfunction
```